# Как програмно можно добраться до системных переменных?

Tags: android

Как програмно можно добраться до системных переменных (скажем к модели смартфона) с последующей возможностью изменения этого поля?

В манифесте пишу:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Получить сами значения можно через Build.DEVICE и Build.MODEL, но чтобы модифицировать эти данные, наверное, нужно добраться к ним используя методы для работы с внешними файлами
Что-то типа

```
File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String[] filesList = storage.list();
        Log.d(TAG, "all files = " + filesList.length);
        for (String file : filesList){
            Log.d(TAG, "file: " + file);
        }
```

но где "копать"?
Может кто сталкивался, есть идеи?

Comment: Эти данные берутся из файла `/system/build.prop`. Программным путем через сам класс `Build` это не получится сделать. Единственный способ - менять build.prop (нужны root права)

Comment: Если речь идет о рут правах и замене системных переменных в коде, то можете, для началв получить содержимое build prop разбив каждую строчку на имя и значение. циклом искать нужное имя (os.brand вроде) и менять значение на другое

Comment: и еще - если речь именно о рут правах - то как-то проще использовать shell. если знаете линукс терминал - то там одной командой все получится :)

Comment: так же хочу предупредить - делайте бекапы! build.prop - очень важный файл в системе, если он будет поврежден - то система не запустится

Comment: @Flippy может стоит оформить полноценный ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `Build` - поставщик данных из файла `/system/build.prop`. Чтобы изменить модель - необходимо его редактировать. Чтобы редактировать системные файлы необходим root-доступ. 
Вы можете, изменить значение строчки `ro.product.model`. Или, например, использовать команду

```
settings put global device_name "Nexus 5"
```

Comment: Да, похоже без рут не обойтись, благодарю за помощь